# How to grep specific errors together with its multi-line description from a log file and output it in a new logfile in Linux?

Tags: linux, grep

Basically I want to grep a specific type of error and its multi-line description from a logfile based on a keyword. For example, the log file may look something like this

```
1  Error - [KEYWORD1] Short description
2  Description
3  Description
4  Description
5
6  Error - [KEYWORD2] Short description
7  Description
8  Description
9  Description
10 
11 Error - [KEYWORD1] Short description
12 Description
13 Description
14 Description
```

Each error is defined by a specific keyword and the errors are seperated by a new line. Is there a way to only grep errors of type [KEYWORD1] together with its description and output it to a new log file?

Expected output:

```
1  Error - [KEYWORD1] Short description
2  Description
3  Description
4  Description

5  Error - [KEYWORD1] Short description
6  Description
7  Description
8  Description
```

I tried something like

grep -E "KEYWORD1" filename | sort | tee new_errorlog.log

but that would only return me the first line without the description. Note that there are error ID / error location details in the description, hence why sort is used and why they are needed. I am kinda new to Linux. So any help is appreciated! Cheers.

*Note: The line numbers are not part of the file

Comment: Are the line numbers part of the file?

Comment: No the line numbers are not part of the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With GNU sed:

```
sed -n '/\[KEYWORD1\]/,/^$/p' file
```

Output:

```
Error - [KEYWORD1] Short description
Description
Description
Description

Error - [KEYWORD1] Short description
Description
Description
Description
```

`^$` matches an empty line.

Answer (score 0):

Cyrus' sed approach is simple and effective, but I think I'd use `awk` for this instead, as it's usually easier to tune your conditions.

```
awk '$1=="Error" && /KEYWORD1/ { s=1 } /^$/ { s=0 } s' file
```

This uses a semaphore or switch, `s`, to determine whether lines should print. An error line with the appropriate keyword turns the switch on, and a blank line turns it off.

If there's the possibility that you may be missing blank lines, you could do something like this instead:

```
awk '$1=="Error" { s=0 } $1=="Error" && /KEYWORD1/ { s=1 } s' file
```

This uses the same condition as before to turn the switch on, but uses the presence of an error line (with or without the keyword) to turn it off.

You could apply the same logic with slightly more complex conditions in order to make things more resilient or reliable.